# БАГ с box-shadow

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Сделал при наведении на ссылку внутреннюю тень, но когда я навожу на неё, появляется нижняя обводка.

Вот код:

```css
.offer__btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: #FF9600;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #000, 1px -1px #000, -1px 1px #000, -1px -1px #000, 3px 3px 6px #000;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.offer__btn:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="offer__btn btn">Заказать звонок</a>
```

Comment: Странно, код дает правильный результат. Возможно, нарушен порядок стилей. Добавьте больше информации.

Comment: не вижу никакой нижней обводки. Только тень. Проверьте ваш браузер, может он совсем древний =)

Answer (score 0):

Стиль написан валидно! (по крайней мере при добавлении только этих стилей, выполняется все как задумано). Проверяйте что написано в стилях в уровнях выше - `a` или `.btn`, соответственно с их свойствами `:hover`